# Module not found: Can't resolve 'module' in 'projectroot\node_modules\load-grunt-tasks\node_modules\resolve-from'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

Anyone got this error as well? No idea what to do. It happened after I installed load-grunt-tasks due to another error that came from there.

Now Im stuck...

When I do `npm i --save resolve-from`

I get this:

> nanogames@0.1.0 C:\projectroot
>   +-- eslint@4.10.0 | `-- require-uncached@1.0.3 |`-- resolve-from@1.0.1
>   +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt@>=0.4.0 `-- resolve-from@4.0.0
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.1.2
>   (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3:
>   wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL
>   DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0
>   (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a
>   peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none was installed. npm WARN
>   load-grunt-tasks@3.5.2 requires a peer of grunt@>=0.4.0 but none was
>   installed. npm WARN react-dom@15.6.2 requires a peer of react@^15.6.2
>   but none was installed.

I narrowed the issue down to the following source:

The error only comes up when I dynamically require images like so:

```
<img src={require(`${this.props.image}`} />
```

Comment: Try `npm install` again?

Comment: did twice, hasnt helped

Comment: Did you delete `/node_modules` folder before doing a fresh install?

Comment: wow that took a while but still nothing...

Comment: Which node/npm version are you using ?

Comment: node --version sais v8.9.0